# Checking input of input field in a Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to check in a Java Servlet if the user entered code10 in a input field, after they pressed the submit button. If that's the case, the form should just go to the next page, if something else than code10 there should just be an alert, and the user should stay on the same page to enter a new code, or leave the input field blank.

These are the important snippets out of my code:

```java
out.println("<head><script type=\"text/javascript\">");
out.println("function check() {");
out.println("var inputDiscountValue = document.getElementById(\"discount\").value;");
out.println("if (inputDiscountValue == 'code10' OR inputDiscountValue == '') {");
out.println("return true;");
out.println("} else {");
out.println("alert('Code not valid');");
out.println("return false;");
out.println("}");
out.println("}");
out.println("</script>");
out.println("</head>");
...
out.println("<form action=\"Servlet2\" method=\"post\">");
out.println("<input type=\"String\" name=\"discount\">");
out.println("<input type=\"submit\" onclick='return check()' value=\"Go\" /> </form>");
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: you really should refrain from mixing java and html code like that. it makes it pretty hard to read/maintain. What actual error do you get? what do you assume that 'check()' function will return?

Comment: There's nothing dynamic about your code, why generate it this way?

Comment: Also please use the submit event and preventDefault instead of submit button click

Comment: You use name="discount" but getElementById. Add the id or change to `document.querySelector("name=discount")` - also it is type="text", not "String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `document.getElementById("discount")` but you did not create an element with that ID.

Change

```
<input type="String" name="discount">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="discount" id="discount">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things that are questionable in your code.

1. Do not use out.println to write html that is not dynamic
2. Do not use click event handler in a form for validation, instead use the submit event
3. it is type="text", not type="String"
4. use the "reserved" attribute to make sure it is filled.

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Discount form</title>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page has loaded
        document.getElementById("discountForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
          const discountField = document.getElementById("discount");
          let inputDiscountValue = discountField.value;
          if (inputDiscountValue !== 'code10') {
            alert('Code not valid');
            discountField.focus();
            e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="discountForm" action="Servlet2" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="discount" id="discount" required />
      <input type="submit" value="Go" />
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```